# Updating row in database has no effect

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm building a python application which purpose is to cyclic poll a Microsoft SQL Server database (every 100-200 ms) for new rows with STATUS = 10.
When there is a result for the query, it should immediatly set STATUS = 15 and process with the queried data. After dataprocessing it should update the Status to 20. The second described update happens in another thread with a separate connection to the same SQL Server.

#### Implementation:

**Select and Update to Status 15:**

```
def _pop_from_db(self):
    if self.db_connection: # connection was established with self.db_connection = pyodbc.connect("connection_string)
        oldest_update_datum_allowed = self.start_up_time_from_db_server + timedelta(minutes=0)
        try:
            with self.db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(

                    """
                    SELECT TOP 1 Id, Number, Status FROM table
                    WHERE UpdateDatum > ? AND Status = ? ORDER BY Id
                    """,
                    [oldest_update_datum_allowed, 10])

                row = cursor.fetchone()
                columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
                if row:
                    m = dict(zip(columns, row))
                    cursor.execute(
                        """
                        UPDATE table SET Status=? WHERE Id=?
                        """,
                        [15, m["Id"]]
                    )
                    self.db_connection.commit()
                    rowcount = cursor.rowcount
                    logging.debug(f"Successfully updated Status for id {m['Id']} to {15} (rowcount {rowcount}).")
                    return m
                return None
        except pyodbc.Error as e:
            logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
            logging.error("Error while querying db. Wait 1 second and try to reconnect")
            sleep(1)
            self._connect_db_server()
            return None
    else:
        logging.error(f"No db connection. Wait 1 second and try to reconnect")
        sleep(1)
        self._connect_db_server()
    return None
```

**Update to Status 20 (different class and different thread):**

```
            try:
                with self.db_connection2.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(
                        """
                        UPDATE table SET Status=?, WHERE Id=?;
                        """,
                        [20, id]
                    )
                    self.db_connection2.commit()
                    rowcount = cursor.rowcount
                    logging.debug(f"Successfully updated Status for id {id} to {20} (rowcount {rowcount}).")
            except pyodbc.OperationalError as e:
                logging.error(f"Exception while updating status for id {id} to {20}.")
                self._connect_db_server()
```

#### Problem:

Updating the Status not always works.
In approx 1 out of 200 times one of the both status updates is not working. I don't get any error messages or exceptions in my application code. Also the returned cursor.rowcount is always 1. But in the Database nothing has changed. The Status remains as before the update statement.

Any ideas, where this strange behaviour may come from? Any suggestions on how the implementation could be improved?

#### Edit:

The database table has some triggers defined. These update a Timestamp field for the updated row, when status gets changed.

#### Edit 2:

I tried different things, like sync all queries in on central thread and update only where status is 10 when updating to 15 and 15 when updating to 20...but nothing did the trick.
Then I used SQL Server profiler from SQL Server Management Studio. There I filtered for Updates in the given table. I can see all updates working correct, even if the error occurs.
So from profiler view the update seems to work.
I see `SQL:BatchCompleted`.
But in the table, data is not updated.

**Question**: Is there a way in SQL Profiler to see if there is any rollback happening?

Comment: Nothing we can tell you. You're just doing to have to add logging to catch the issue

Comment: Which one fails? Can it be either?

Comment: Do you mean logging on SQL Server?

Comment: Select works. But Update fails. Sometimes the Status update to 15 fails. Sometimes Update to 20 fails.

Comment: Probably there's some other exception happening in the processing which you don't catch properly. You need to post the threading code

Comment: @siggemannen I could change my except block to be broader and catch all Exceptions happening during the SQL query. Thread code isn't much more. Just a function called do_it() which puts the queried data into a fifo register, where another thread can get it from.

Comment: that's a start, but i suspect the problem is somewhere else, maybe in the processing or how you handle the threads themselves. do you use some thread lib? Also, can there be some application that reads the same table and perhaps write to it? it would be interesting to add AND status = 15 (or 10) to make sure noone removed the carpet from under your feet. Also, perhaps log the row changes in the trigger as debugging measure

Comment: @siggemen I just use the standard Python thread from threading.

Comment: @siggemannen Yes, there is are other applications which fill the data initially and also querying for my status 20. But I don't have any further knowledge about the implementation of the

Comment: I'v added some information to my question, which I got using SQL profiler.

Comment: It seems the problem is solved. I will check it further and give a detailed answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some hard Resarch, here more details I found out about the situation and my hopefully (final) solution:

*Few words in advance:*
*The SQL Server instance is not under my control. The table was not created and configured by me. It is under control of another company. The described `SELECT` and `Update` process is a interface proposed by the other company, which I had to implement into my software.*

#### What I did:

To get more details about what is/was going on I decided to use SQL Profiler (I guess the more modern way would have been Extenend Events in SQL Server. But the SQL Server instance I had to deal with was an old version without Extended Events).
After figuring out how to filter the huge amount of messages going on on the server (it is a very busy SQL Server instance in a factory controlling the production), I had found a setup, which gave me more information.

#### What I found:

In SQL Profiler each Update query was logged with `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:BatchCompleted`. Between them there always was a transaction happening (Begin and Commit). In the cases where the UPDATE query wasn't working as expected, I noticed a transaction rollback of these transactions.
I wanted to work without SQL Transactions, so I set `autocommit = True` in *pyodbc*. The amount of transactions reduced and I had the feeling the error occured fewer times than before. But it still happened sometimes with the described transaction rollback between `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:BatchCompleted`.
I tooked a deeper look at the database and table configuration. I noticed some trigger defined for the table. This trigger did some logging into another table. At the end of the trigger, there was a statement which deleted log messages older than *x* days. My guess: This delete might cause some kind of blocking and maybe also a transaction rollback.

#### Solution

I disabled the trigger which inserted into log table and deletes old log messages. This seemed to solve the problem. The system now runs more the 36 hours and updated the status more than 30,000 times without any error.
I don't know why there still is a SQL transaction between `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:BatchCompleted`. But I'm happy with the result.

#### Conclusion

In the end it wasn't a Problem with *pyodbc*, python or my poor implementation. Error was server side.